# Firefox not browsing, fails to open settings, crashes when resize

Tags: node.js, npm, firefox

I installed npm and then node js in windows 10.
Later on the firefox was encounting error 0xc0000022 and could not browse at all.

I reinstalled firefox, problem remains.

Earlier when trying to browse it was opening a fail tab with a failure message (without code) but now it does not react when hit enter to browse.

mozglue.dll exists.

Somewhere I read Microsoft Visual Studio has some kind of dependencies and I tried to reinstall it.
Firefox still does not browse.

I flushed dns.
I reset winsock.
I disabled network.http.http3.enabled from about:config

Comment: while reinstall encounters 0xc0000022 error

Comment: failure message : Gah. Your tab just crashed.

Comment: it cannot browse even about:config anymore